# Huge VRAM usage in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: drivers, unity, gnome, amd-graphics

I'm currently using Ubuntu 17.10 with AMD HD 7770 gpu. When I open radeontop I can see that whole VRAM is consumed, when displaying only desktop and terminal. I'm connecting it with stuttering which happens sometimes. It occurs on both Unity and Gnome.

Can't really Ubuntu handle itself with 1GB of VRAM???

Is it OK for Unity Desktop or Gnome to consume so much VRAM? Is it a bug?

GPU: AMD HD7770

Driver: amdgpu / DRM 3.19.0 / 4.14.13-041413-generic, LLVM 6.0.0

Kernel: 4.14.13-041413-generic